# 1.5.0 or better of the Subversion Python bindings

Tags: python, svn

When I try to commit with Tortoise SVN, it shows that :
post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
Error: You need version 1.5.0 or better of the Subversion Python bindings. 
 
How should I solve this?
Thanks！

Comment: Is there someone in charge of the server and the hook scripts?

Comment: i can deal with the hooks

Comment: Originally,there's no mailer.py under /hooks of the repos.So I download one from apache and move it under /hooks. After chmod the file to be executable, there comes the problem. I've upgraded the whole server once.I'm only looking for solution to make files accessible on web after I commit the code so I chose to use the hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an outdate of python-svn binding. You need to install the newer kits:
from here:
http://pysvn.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=1768

I am not sure whether Tortois installation brings it's own version of these python-bindings.

Comment: I've installed the latest kit on server but the problem still exists.

Comment: Try: apt-get install subversion-tools